# Mediaelements.js Unspecified error

Tags: wordpress, mediaelement.js, unspecified

Im using mediaelements.js on a wordpress site with an MP4 video.

In IE9/Firefox/Chrome it works fine.

But in IE 7/8 when clicking on play u get the following error:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; CMNTDF; BRI/1; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; BOIE9;ENGB)
Timestamp: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 13:34:50 UTC

Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 49
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://website.local/page/independence/
```

I have even tried using the wordpress plugin they provide and get the same result.

anyone else had an issue like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of WordPress 3.6, mediaelements.js is included in WordPress and videos can be embedded using the Post Editor as outlined at http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds.  It has been a month or two since I last looked, but I believe they stopped developing the wordpress plugin when it was decided it would be included in WP 3.6.

To answer you particular error specifically, can you provide either a snippet or URL to the page?